# smb.conf variable %m doenst work with mount.cifs

Tags: linux, mount, samba, nautilus

I noticed a difference between mount.cifs and gvfs when connection to my samba server.

Entry in `smb.conf` I like to connect to ...

```
[backup]
path = /srv/smb/backups/%m
comment = Inkrementelle Backups vom System
browseable = no
guest ok = no
writeable = yes
valid users = bak
inherit owner = yes
```

Notice the `%m` in path !

When using nautilus (gvfs) every thing works as expected.

But `%m` gets ignored when using `mount.cifs`.

A picture say more than 1000 words ...
[image: https://photos.app.goo.gl/VZoz8bXUhqjaxeIi2]

How to get mount.cifs behave like gvfs ?

I tried to change the protocol to 1.0, 2.0, 2.1 and 3.0 but nothing changed at all.

Has it some to do with NetBIOS, because I dont use it, instead I use dhcp & bind. Maybe I have a wrong bind configuration, but I cant find any error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We're talking about

> `%m`
> the NetBIOS name of the client machine
>
> This parameter is not available when Samba listens on port 445, as clients no longer send this information. If you use this macro in an include statement on a domain that has a Samba domain controller be sure to set in the `[global]` section `smb ports = 139`. This will cause Samba to not listen on port 445 and will permit include functionality to function as it did with Samba 2.x.

([source](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/current/man-html/smb.conf.5.html)).

Then there is this mount option in [`man 8 mount.cifs`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mount.cifs):

> `netbiosname=arg`
> When mounting to servers via port 139, specifies the RFC1001 source name to use to represent the client netbios machine name when doing the RFC1001 netbios session initialize.

Thus I think you should mount with:

```
mount -t cifs -o credentials=/root/.smbcredentials,netbiosname=…
```

You can also add `port=139` option. This way `mount` won't lose time trying to connect on port 445.